# Lighttpd start error. Cannot write to log

Tags: lighttpd, installation

I'm following a tutorial to help me install the lighttpd server software on my Mandriva box.
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/installing-and-configuring-lighttpd-webserver-howto.html

I think that I've done everything necessary but I keep getting this error whenever I want to start the server.

```
[root@localhost lighttpd]# /etc/init.d/lighttpd start
Starting lighttpd: 2009-07-28 13:00:15: (log.c.84) opening errorlog  '/var/log/lighttpd/error.log' failed: Permission denied
2009-07-28 13:00:15: (server.c.893) Opening errorlog failed. Going down.
```

I don't understand what's causing this problem. I'm running this server as root, there should be no permission problem.

Comment: Can you post the output of <pre>ls -l /var/log/lighttpd/error.log</pre>

Answer (score 2):

Does litehttpd change its ID to another user when started like apache?  If so you will need to make sure the log folder/file is writable by that user.